# Browse a image from SD card to show it in image view in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

am use activity as a dialog.In that i have button to browse and select the image to show it in image view.

**My Dialog activity code and browse image**

```
public class Update_profile extends Activity{

private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 1;

private View rootView;
Button save,browse_image;
ImageView profile_pic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    setContentView(R.layout.update_profile);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    this.rootView=findViewById(R.id.update_profile_details);
    profile_pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.update_profile_picture);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    browse_image = (Button)findViewById(R.id.browse_image);
    browse_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    Bitmap bitmap   = null;
    String path     = "";

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData(); 
        path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery
        Log.v("Path", ""+path);

        if (path == null)
            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager
        Log.v("Path", ""+path);

        if (path != null) 
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    } else {
        path    = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
        Log.v("Path", ""+path);
        bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }

    profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);     
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj      = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor       = managedQuery( contentUri, proj, null, null,null);

    if (cursor == null) return null;

    int column_index    = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   Rect rect = new Rect();
   rootView.getHitRect(rect);
   if (!rect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())){
       setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); 
          return true;
   }
      return false;       
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**My manifest code to change the activity as a dialog**

```
<activity
        android:name="test.Update_profile"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

When am using above browse images code in ordinary activity means it fetch the images and show it in image view but in this dialog activity.its now able to pick the image.I want to pic the image from dialog activity.am not able to solve this issue.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: if i give u all image view then could u set in grid view to all image and after that u can also show your image on click of grid view element

Comment: @BhanuSharma i want the path of the image.

Comment: ohk see my answer i give u all detail with file path also dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to retrive direct from gallary then use this code 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

this is my method for getting all file from sdcard and u just save this in one datacontroller class ohk dude

```
private void getallimages()
            {
                String[] STAR = { "*" };


                final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID , MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
                Cursor imagecursor = ((Activity) cntx).managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, orderBy);
                int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                int imgNameIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int count = imagecursor.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                    ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                    imageItem.id = id;
                    imageItem.filePath = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    lastId = id;
                    imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cntx.getContentResolver(), id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                    imageItem.selection = false; //newly added item will be selected by default
                    controller.images.add(imageItem);
                }

            }
```

this is ImageItem wrapper class

```
 public class ImageItem {
            public boolean selection=true;
            public int id;
            public Bitmap img;
            public String filePath;
            public String fileType;
    }
```

Comment: what is that **lastId(its Previous image path)**.

Comment: just delete this line forgot this coz this is i use to maintain position in list view so u just avoid this

Comment: thanks.it retrieve the all image path.but i need selective image path(what am said in my question).

Comment: is it possible to do like that.

Comment: ohk means u want to open direct media gallary and when u click any image then it will show in your app is it u want

Comment: that project is working.am using that code in my dialog activity its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this : 

    public class EMView extends Activity {
    ImageView img,img1;
    int column_index;
    Intent intent=null;
    // Declare our Views, so we can access them later
    String logo,imagePath,Logo;
    Cursor cursor;
    //YOU CAN EDIT THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

     String selectedImagePath;
    //ADDED
     String filemanagerstring;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gimg1);



    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
            // select a file
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);


        }
    });
}

//UPDATED
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            //OI FILE Manager
            filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            //MEDIA GALLERY
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);


            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

           imagePath.getBytes();
           TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
           txt.setText(imagePath.toString());


           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

           img1.setImageBitmap(bm);



        }

    }

}

//UPDATED!
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
 imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

}
```

Comment: For simple activity your answer is working in fine but not for dialog(am use activity as a dialog).